# Trying to install pg gem fails during ruby project build

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rvm, pg

I'm attempting to build a ruby project which uses postgres running locally. Build fails on the pg gem install. I get this error

```
$ gem install pg -v '0.12.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /path/to/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
    --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
```

so... I pass the pg_config path, and get a different error:

```
$ gem install pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config -v '0.12.2'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config
```

Very confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you have **libpq-dev** package installed. If you don't, install it and try installing pg again without the **--with-pg-config** parameter.

In regards to the **--with-pg-config** parameter:

When passing parameters to the gem you're installing you must use two dashes before the two dashes from the option, like so:

```
gem install gem-name -- --gem-option
```

So what you want to run in order to achieve installing **pg** with the **--with-pg-config** option is:

```
gem install pg -v '0.12.2' -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config
```

**EDIT**

Also, one last tip, after searching a bit more about this issue I found that your ruby version and architecture might affect pg's installation, I'm quoting [this link](http://www.kacode.com/v4328-.html):

> I was hesitant to uninstall everything so I just uninstalled Ruby and reinstalled with the option set to 64-bit only (platform: "x86_64-darwin12.2.0"). After reinstalling Ruby with this option, the PG gem installed without hitch and I am back to being happy.

Comment: Yeah, I actually got around it using

$ export CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config"
$ gem install pg -v '0.12.2'